# Where to call Office.initialize with Excel JS custom functions files?

Tags: office-js

I'm creating a custom function in Excel JS that I want to use other Office.js features with. I'm trying to initialize Office.js in the custom function like so:

```
async function getData(indicator, date, handler) {
await Office.onReady();
if (date !== "earliest" && date !== "latest" && !date.includes("-")) {
  const newDate = new Date((parseFloat(date) - (25567 + 2))*86400*1000); // Converts Excel date, days since 1900, to YYYY-MM-DD as per https://gist.github.com/christopherscott/2782634
  date = formatDate(newDate)
}
dd_value = new DDValue("A1", indicator, date)
console.log(dd_value)
try {
  await Excel.run(function (context) {
      var range = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
      range.load("address");

      return context.sync()
          .then(function () {
              console.log(`The address of the selected range is "${range.address}"`);
          });
  }).catch(errorHandlerFunction);
} catch(error) {
  console.log("ERROR")
  console.log(error)
}
}
```

However, I'm getting the following errors:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: context`

`Uncaught Error: Office.js has not fully loaded. Your app must call "Office.onReady()" as part of it's loading sequence (or set the "Office.initialize" function). If your app has this functionality, try reloading this page.`

I've also tried to initialize Office.js in the index.html page (just a script in the header), but this hasn't worked either.

Has anyone tried to implement the other Office.js features in custom functions yet? How did the Office.js initialization work for you?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

this isn’t possible today, but is on our radar.

a) We are actively developing the feature to pass in the address of the calling cell of the function (selected range doesn’t work in this context as the user could have selected a different cell than your function is entered on).

b) if you need additional APIs, would like to know your scenario? We will expose office.js to custom functions in some fashion but we are generally being cautious here as calling back to excel during a calculation can lead to unpredictable results (as exists today for XLLand VBA UDFs).

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again, Keyur!!

My scenario is still a bit abstract but basically I'm using custom functions to send request to my API and populate the cell with the returned data. Multiple cells with this function throttled my API and Excel, however. So now I am trying to make the function add the cell address and api details to a string. This string will be a url that I contact my API with.

Comment: So basically, I want to use custom functions to build an array of objects where each object is {cell address, api parameters} and then I will build an API url endpoint from that string to contact the API. Then populating each cell (with the cell address) with the correct data. This reduces an http request made by each function call to one http request for all the custom function cells. Please let me know if I need to explain anything else.

The Excel JS API and custom functions have been excellent so far, by the way! We've been able to accomplish loads.

Comment: 1. User enters formula into cell ("ua_fx.usd", "latest") [api details]
2. We create object Object("ua_fx.usd", "latest", cell number)
3. We store object in our class variable, probably an array [Object, Object, Object("ua_fx", "latest")]... and put array in Settings object
4. We generate an api_string (no longer a class variable) with the above format
5. We contact the API with that string and get the data
6. We go through the Object array again and populate all the cell numbers with the corresponding data

This is the algorithm I wanted to implement

Comment: Again, we were contacting the API with each custom function before which lead to a lot of "N/A" values in the cell because we were throttling excel and our API with http requests.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! What type of addin are you building for? You can ping me offline at kepatel@microsoft.com.

Comment: For your scenario there is a different mechanism by which you can batch, which does not involve needing the address of the calling cell (instead you queue up each call through a timer, then process the queue, make the api call, and resolve each promise with each result). a link From the promise to the cell essentially maps the value back.  We are actually working on an article that outlines this and I think it should be published soon. Happy to have you try it out before it goes public.

Comment: Hi @KeyurPatel-MSFT, have you guys wrote the article? Can you please share docs about this technique?